# How to allow new users to post without moderation in phpBB 3?

Tags: phpbb, administration, moderation

I am creating a new forum used phpBB3. New users can post, but I have to manually approve them. How can I disable this so users can post without me having to approve the content manually?

Comment: Can post without approval is not on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank for [William D. Edwards's suggest](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/69304/44886). This is my specific solution:
**Step 1**: Log in to phpBB admin panel

**Step 2**: Navigate to Permissions
[image]

**Step 3**: Adjust posting permissions settings
From the user group list select “Registered users” or "Newly registered users". This way we will be editing permissions for all registered users. To open permissions management page, click on “Submit” button.
[image]

**Step 4**: Adjust Advanced Permissions
Choose "Can post without approval"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. This is a permission issue which is enabled by default in phpBB. As I am using XenForo these days, I'm not sure what exact solution I used but here are helpful articles:

- https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1250835
- http://www.host1plus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/phpbb/phpbb-administration/how-to-allow-users-to-post/
- http://www.phpbb3bbcodes.com/viewtopic.php?t=462
- http://www.phpbbhacks.com/forums/how-to-disable-approval-vt74649.html
- https://theadminzone.com/threads/get-rid-of-manual-post-approval.75779/

Comment: @dovy Great. I hope you'll fix this problem, I know it's very frustrating!

Comment: @dovy If you have the answer to this question, please edit my answer with the real solution so it becomes a better one which will more likely help future visitors.

Comment: @dovy This is a reminder for my latest comment ^

Comment: ok, I have been post the answer. I also want using XenForo like you.

Comment: @dovy Great! :) That'd be a good step. If you need help with it, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

On the most recent version of PHPBB at the time of this posting, 3.1.8. It is slightly different than the correct post above.

Open the administration panel, click on the permissions tab, then group forum permissions. See "look up usergroup", select registered users click submit, Select the forum or alternatively select the all forums checkbox, at the right select advanced permissions, on the posts tab is "Can post without approval" set to yes.

Comment: Not found the "Adjust posting permissions settings" in phpbb3