# How to allow new users to post without moderation in phpBB 3.2.1?

Tags: phpbb

I installed phpbb3 with namecheap's control panel.

The standard method of disabling the approval requirement is to go to "permissions" -> "group permission" -> "submit" -> "advanced" -> "misc."

However, there's nothing to change about post approval - as you can see here: [image: phpbb321]

So, how do I disable the requirement for posts to be approved?

Comment: I seriously hope you are not doing the a public web server. If you are, then that is not only extremely foolish, but irresponsible as well. Harsh language I know. However, I am telling you something you need to hear. If this is on an intranet, then that should be okay.

Comment: Yes, it would be foolish. This is very private.

Comment: Good! ;-) We do get people who want user generated content and do not want  to do the work to moderate the site. We get questions similar to this for public sites all the time! I wish I had an answer for you on this. It is possible that the feature does not exist these days. I have not used any forum in a very long time. Sorry. I am hoping that there is a solution for you. Cheers!!

Comment: Specifically this answer is for phpBB 3.1.8 and later: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/92416/14543

Comment: No joy, Stephen - that location doesn't exist in my 3.2.1.